# Where does mobilefirst-qa store the selected user?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

After choosing the user in the login view, the library saves this information somewhere so that the app has not to ask for the user again.

Where is this information stored? I need to know how to reset this setting for a fresh start?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to switch between users, there is an easy way to do this when the app starts up.

On iOS, there is a brief message shown at the top of the screen when the app starts up, if you click on that, you can change to a different user.

On Android, there is a notification that you can reach by pulling down from the top of the screen once the app has started. Click on the notification and you can change user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, bout this was not my question. I want to know where this information is stored. I already noticed this message that you mentioned.

Comment: I understand I'm, unfortunately, not answering your question directly.  The problem with answering it directly is that the location, contents and formatting of this information would all be subject to change as they are part of the internal workings of the SDK.  Anything I would tell you now could easily break when an updated version of the SDK is delivered. 

Can you give some additional information about what you're trying to accomplish? Then I'll, hopefully, be able to give you some guidance on how to do this without getting into the inner workings of the SDK.